# how to recompile cv_bridge w/o optimization

Tags: ros, optimization, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

For some particular reason, I need to step into `/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp` for debugging purpose, and I want to examine the value of `int source_type` in the function of `toCvCopy`. However, when I print `source_type` in gdb, it says "value optimized out". So how can I re-compile & build cv_bridge without optimization, so I can examine the value of `source_type`?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11619/how-to-recompile-cv_bridge-w/o-optimization/) by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't actually try this, but I believe this should be the general procedure:

First, add a directory for svn-based installs, for example

```
mkdir ~/ros
```

Next, add it to your path, by editing `/opt/ros/electric/setup.sh` to say

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/<username>/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks
```

Clone the svn version of vision_opencv

```
cd ~/ros
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/trunk
```

Edit the `CMakeLists.txt` in `cv_bridge` to say:

```
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

Finally, compile it:

```
rosmake cv_bridge
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1